# glyphicons CSS not loading

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am getting error in browser console as ::

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

When I do inspect element, I see ::

```
::before == $0
```

What does this mean ?

the css in inspect element shows::

```
a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e260';
}
```

what does it mean `content: '\e259'`; ?

Comment: `content: '\e259'`  is a menu down icon. From glyphicon: `.glyphicon-menu-down:before { content: "\e259"; }`. Its just a special character value to link the icon to your css: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Comment: If you have recently upgraded from Bootstrap 3.x to 4.x you should keep in mind that they removed icon support from the framework - you now need to import whichever icon package you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have imported Bootstrap?

Make sure you imported bootstrap properly.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/